# Grid.Mvc Filtering

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcgrid

I am using Grid.Mvc for grid. I want to use Filtering feature of the same. I set the `Filterable(true)` for the column I need to get the filter. The filter icon appears. But when I click on it, nothing happens. I mean the pop-up never comes on.

More info of my grid: The Grid is on a Partial View. The Model is a `List<>`. I have the paging and sorting work on the same grid.

Comment: try adding required javascript and css jquery.js,bootstrap.js,gridmvc.js and bootstrap.css,bootstrap-theme.css and Gridmvc.css

Comment: @ArjunVachhani, everything is in place. Thats what is baffling me.

Comment: can you please add some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. In fact, this was a ajax call on which I was filling a partial view with Grid.Mvc. So, in this case, you need to refresh the grid, once it is placed in the div.

$(".grid-mvc").gridmvc();